# HandlebarsJS {{#if}} statement inside {{#each}}

Tags: backbone.js, handlebars.js

I have Backbone App where I use Handlebars to render my data in my HTML files. So, I try to achieve that if a Collection should be empty e.g have no data, there should just be a simple `<p>`-tag which tells the user that there is currently no data. In this case, if there is a biography available, it should be displayed and if not, a simple text like "there's no biography yet" or something like that. So I tried this:

```
{{#each this}}
    {{#if this}}
    <p>{{bio}}</p>
    {{else}}
    <p>There is no biography yet!</p>
    {{/if}}
{{/each}}
```

but with no luck! How can I achieve this?

Comment: This stands for Collection ?

Comment: No, thats my HTML template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

give this a try. `#unless` stands for `if not`.

```
{{#each this}}
    <p>{{bio}}</p>
{{/each}}
{{#unless this}}
    <p>There is no biography yet!</p>
{{/unless}}
```